# UPDATE, AND INSERT to different tables if condition [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

please help me to build a mysql query that update, and insert datas to different tables at the same time:

first query is rather simple:

```
UPDATE newser SET total_rating = '1' WHERE blogid = '136' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO user_votes (blogid, userid) VALUES('133', '34');
```

But what I wanna to achieve is UPDATE the newser table IF there is a lack of blogid, userid.
So the query should looks like this:

```
UPDATE newser SET total_rating = '1' WHERE blogid = '136' LIMIT 1; WHERE THERE IS LACK OF:
blogid = '136' AND userid ='34'
```

Other Words:

```
if user_votes contains blogid = '136' AND userid ='34' THEN UPDATE, and INSERT CANNOT BE DONE.
else UPDATE, AND INSERT RUNS NORMAL.
```

Comment: 'update, and insert datas to different tables ' - You cannot do this in a single query perhaps in a stored procedure. Also a worked example would help clarify.

Comment: ok, and how to do that in a single query without insert. I move insert to another query.